# How to find out if an app uses HTTP Live Streaming using a packet sniffer?

Tags: iphone, http, audio, streaming, live

I need to test the application I developed, that uses HTTP Live Streaming ( audio only ) and I would like to see how it works in comparison with other similar apps. How can I conclude that an app uses HTTP Live Streaming by using a packet sniffer?

Comment: The question is how to use a packet sniffer to inspect the stream, or you already know how to use it and you want to know what to look for?

Comment: @Radu, after reading the question, I get the impression that the questioner knows how to use  a packet sniffer and wants to know what to look for to confirm the usage of HTTP Live Streaming.

Comment: Indeed, I would like to recognize if a certain application uses HTTP Live Streaming by using a packet sniffer.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a request for a playlist file with an .m3u8 extension and in the response look for `#EXTM3U` on the first line. The [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-20) should give you all the information you need to interpret the rest of the traffic.

Here are [some values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTTP_Live_Streaming_Metadata_Spec/2/2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010435-CH2-DontLinkElementID_7) you might find useful if you want to look at the stream closer.

I have never tried this tool but Apple [released](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2235/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010221-CH1-VALIDATORTOOL) a stream validator, all you need is the playlist URL.

Bear in mind that it's possible to use a number of different streaming technologies and it's a popular practice with alot of services to use the one which makes most sense at the time. If you don't simulate the correct environment you might never get an HLS stream at all.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the answer, but a long time has passed since 2011 and I won't be able to test your response. Hope it will help others :)